# Continue without a default route?

Tags: custom-distributions, custom-installer

I have to do a complete unattended installation of a node with Ubuntu12.04. 
I have given following options in preseed file

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eth0
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean true
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true
d-i netcfg/use_autoconfig  boolean false
d-i netcfg/network-manager boolean false
d-i netcfg/no_default_route boolean true
d-i netcfg/enable boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.103
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.0.0
d-i netcfg/Confirm_static boolean true
```

Still d-i is asking "Continue without a default route? ", i have to say YES manullay. 
How can i preseed this  while d-i Configure the network

---

Even after setting default gateway & name server still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you didn't define a default gateway, you need to use:

```
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.1
```

Of course the ip address in the above command is just a guest, you should adjust it to the correct gateway of your network.

I can't test it, but it's very likely that you will need this too:

```
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 192.168.1.1
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
```

The first one will set the dns, I don't know why or if the second one is necessary but it appears in the documentation so...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `d-i netcfg/no_default_route boolean true` does not work and is ignored.
The only solution I found is switching to a different tty and run the following

```
ip route add 172.31.1.1 dev ens3
ip route add default via 172.31.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, but I added the setting to the 'pxelinux.cfg/default' menu and solved it.

```
menu label ^Ubuntu 16.04 (Automatic)
kernel Ubuntu16/linux
append auto=true priority=critical vga=788 initrd=Ubuntu16/initrd.gz netcfg/no_default_route=true preseed/url=http://192.168.1.10/preseed.seed
```